# Google Maps API v3 my map does not center on kml polygon

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, maps

my problem is all in the title, I built a map with a center and zoom and I load a kml file representing a specific area according to the user's choice. It works fine, except that my map does not auto center and zoom on the loaded polygon. It zooms but only the upper part of the polygon is visible. The PreserveViewport option does not help me more as I set it to true I don't get any change as expected... Maybe is there a way to get the kml polygon's center in order to re-set the map's center ? I've browsed the web with no success. You can have a look [here](http://parlera.fr/wp/cartographie-des-dispositifs/)

Comment: Please post your code(preferably a simple example that shows the issue) in the question, not just a link to your page.

Comment: It is a problem with the iframe.  It works on the [page loaded inside the iframe](http://parlera.fr/wp/externes/cartographie/map3.php)

Comment: There is no problem with the centering . The iframe is to small, it doesn't show the complete map(you may have noticed that the google-logo and the copyrights at the bottom are missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually working, forgot tu update my css for map  in order to get it show entirely. Thanks again, you saved me lots of time.